# Text Data not sorting as desired

Tags: microsoft-excel, sorting

```
ESXi 5.0.0
ESXi 5.0.0
ESXi 5.0.0
ESXi 5.0.0
ESXi 5.0.0
ESXi 5.5.0
ESXi 5.5.0
ESXi 5.5.0
EXSi 4.0.0
EXSi 4.1.0
EXSi 4.1.0
EXSi 4.1.0
EXSi 4.1.0
EXSi 4.1.0
EXSi 4.1.0
EXSi 5.0.0
EXSi 5.0.0
EXSi 5.0.0
EXSi 5.0.0
EXSi 5.0.0
EXSi 5.0.0
EXSi 5.0.0
EXSi 5.5.0
EXSi 5.5.0
EXSi 5.5.0
```

When using the above as one item per cell in a column, the desired result is,

```
EXSi 4.0.0

.
EXSi 4.1.0

.
ESXi 5.0.0
.
.
EXSi 5.5.0
```

The result after sorting just the column is:

```
ESXi 5.0.0
ESXi 5.0.0
ESXi 5.0.0
ESXi 5.0.0
ESXi 5.0.0
ESXi 5.5.0
ESXi 5.5.0
ESXi 5.5.0
EXSi 4.0.0
EXSi 4.1.0
EXSi 4.1.0
EXSi 4.1.0
EXSi 4.1.0
EXSi 4.1.0
EXSi 4.1.0
EXSi 5.0.0
EXSi 5.0.0
EXSi 5.0.0
EXSi 5.0.0
EXSi 5.0.0
EXSi 5.0.0
EXSi 5.0.0
EXSi 5.5.0
EXSi 5.5.0
EXSi 5.5.0
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

You're asking it to sort alphabetically, so it will sort by the letters, then if the letters match, by the numbers. It's doing what's expected. -

- E**S**Xi 5
- E**S**Xi 5.5
- E**X**Si 4
- E**X**Si 4.1
- E**X**Si 5
- E**X**Si 5.5

What you need is a helper column next to it like `=Right(A1,5)` and sort ascending on that column.

Or go text to columns and sort on the numbers.

[image]

Comment: It happens to all of us!